# What is the proper way to call reloadData on the TableView of one ViewController from another class?

Tags: ios, xml, swift, parsing

I have and Parser Class (which parses XML data using NSXMLParser and its delegate methods) and a TableViewController (that displays the XML data). In the Parser Class, I retrieve the XML data using the following code:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            print("Data not received")
            return
        }

        let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data)
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
    }
task.resume()
```

After parsing the data, I create a list of objects which the TableViewController will use to populate the cells of its TableView. Then, the Parser Class has to tell the TableViewController to reload the data in its TableView. I do this by adding the following code in my TableViewController:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(EventsTableViewController.reloadData), name: "reloadData", object: nil)

func reloadData(notification: NSNotification) {
    if notification.name == "reloadData" {
        events = eventParser.events
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
        addLocalNotifications()
    }
}
```

I also add this code to my Parser Class at the end of the dataTaskWithURL(url) completion handler above:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("reloadData", object: self)
```

This works and the data is reloaded but I wanted to ask, is this the right way to do this? Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have to notify A class from B class when certain event is occurred, you have two ways, 1. You can either write a Delegate. 2. You can use NSNotificationCenter as you have already did. You can use any one, NSNotificationCenter is easy and required to write less code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @BharatModi!

Answer (score 0):

Use a delegate that is the proper way to reload table from another controller.